# Is there any difference between 'document.getElementById()' and 'document.getElementById',can Round brackets make any difference?

Tags: javascript

given a piece of the code:

```
init: function () {
    var tablebody;
    if (!document.getElementById() || !document.createTextNode) return;
    var ts = document.getElementsByTagName('table');
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Please provide more information: what do you want to achieve, what doesn't work, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes!

```
document.getElementById()
```

This will call the function.

```
document.getElementById
```

This will check if the `getElementById` is defined on `document` and return it.

Comment: if I use round brackets,must I add arguements in it?And like the function to lowerCase(), why it always uses round brackets?

Comment: @HuiAn You have to provide an argument to the function

Comment: So you mean if I use round brackets, I have to provide an argument to the function,but toLowerCase(), it doesn't have any argument,why many people use round brackets? Just a habit?

Comment: @HuiAn If you want to call a function with arguments you have to add those in `()`. `toLowerCase()` don't need argument and `getElementById()` does.